# How to Customize the tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I need to add image to the tabbarcontroller. I included navigationcontroller as a tabbar item in tabbarcontroller. So how can i add image to the tabbarcontroller.

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; 
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];  
tabBarController.delegate=self;


Dashboard_iPhone *dash = [[Dashboard_iPhone alloc] init];
UINavigationController *tabItem0 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dash] autorelease];
tabItem0.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    TrackProgram_iPhone *rep = [[TrackProgram_iPhone alloc] init];
UINavigationController *tabItem1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rep] autorelease];
tabBarController.tabBarItem.title=@"TrackProgram";  
tabItem1.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


TrackClinic_iPhone *loc = [[TrackClinic_iPhone alloc] init];
UINavigationController *tabItem2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loc] autorelease];
tabBarController.tabBarItem.title=@"TrackClinic ";
tabItem2.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];



tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabItem0,tabItem1,tabItem2,nil];


[self.view insertSubview:tabBarController.view belowSubview:dash.view ];    

[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

please help me to add image to tabbarcontroller.

Comment: do you mean icons for tabbar items? or a background, or even something else? Please be more specific.

Comment: the title and your description is confusing. do you ask how to add image on `tabbar` or how to customizing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom TabBarController. various licenses.

https://github.com/aalittle/ALCustomTabBarController

https://github.com/i300/TweetBotTabBar

https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController

http://www.mobilebricks.com/ios/altabbarcontroller

Answer (score 8):

```
self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CamListIconNew.png"];
```

Add above line to each of your view controller.
Also if you want total tabbar customized.Please go though following link.
https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/downloads