# Back ground color of tab bar More button view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

[image: Can we change background color of this view?]

I want change color of this view. I want tabbar more button view color same as app color,not white. how it is possible.

Comment: You want to change tabBar item color or the More tab view controller color?

Comment: Just see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13251455/1495442) ,we customize tab bar view color

Comment: More Tab ViewController color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fo this you have to customize `moreNavigationController`. One solution is to subclass your `UITabBarController` and add following on `- (void)viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UINavigationController *moreController = self.moreNavigationController;
    //if u want to custamize navigationBar u can customize
    //moreController.navigationBar

    if ([moreController.topViewController.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        //Custamize your tableview here
        UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)moreController.topViewController.view;
        //Change the color of tableView
        [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        moreController.topViewController.view = tableView;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you

to customize the `tabBarItem` you can follow other answers.